Вставка пробелов через определенное количество строк
В Notepad++ есть определенное количество строк, например 500 000.
Необходимо через каждые 20 000 строк, вставить 20 пустых строк, и дальше по файлу так же.
20 000 строк с информацией - 20 пустых строк, 20 000 строк с информацией - 20 пустых строк.

"вставило 20 пробелов" --- Пробелов или всё же пустых строк?

Прошу прощения - пустых строк


Найти: (([\s\S]*?\n){5}) (вместо 5-ки подставьте необходимое количество строк);
Заменить на: $1\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n;
Зациклить поиск;
Режим поиска: Регулярные выражения
Заменить все


Этот вариант у меня не работает.

@АндрейЛещенко, значит Вы неправильно скопировали или отметили не все условия.

У меня кстати тоже не работает... не ищет ничего.  ( https://i.sstatic.net/Ae0L9.png )

@АлексейШиманский, а теперь? Wrap around... Тьфу...

Чёт нет.. ни с wrap ни без..... может у меня блокнот старый хз... чёт он не понимает....У ТС видимо такж

Да, не проходит у меня. Попробую обновится. Обновление не помогло.

@АндрейЛещенко, https://i.sstatic.net/jBKOv.jpg

@UModeL https://ibb.co/60mmWLZ

@АндрейЛещенко, Режим поиска: Регулярные выражения

@UModeL Есть контакт! Но у меня это не работает на 20 000 и на 15 000 также - "Недопустимое регулярное выражение". 10 000 проходит отлично

@АндрейЛещенко, теоретически можно использовать максимальное значение для 32-х битного числа, но видимо это ограничения Npp.
